# How to fix proxy 407 error for botFramework?

Tags: proxy, botframework, fiddler, http-status-code-407

I am working with microsoft bot emulator and everytime I make a request to an external link my office proxy blocks it and application returns 407 error. To work around this I tried following hacks.

***Hack #1:***

Used fiddler 4 with auto authenticate rule enabled. But I found it doesn't work for ntlm proxy.
I also found that the request which are completing with 200 status code has a **proxy-authorization** header with some encoded content. but I don't know how to set this header for all the requests.

***Hack #2:***
Installed and ran a [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) proxy, still same error.

I am using Micosoft bot framework 4 with dotnet core and bot emulator 4.10, Os: windows 7

Please help let me know if I can somehow make it work around ntlm proxy.

Comment: Looks like the office network is very restricted when it comes to network access. May be you should better talk to your IT department if you can't get a PC that is located in a different subnet that is less restrictive.

Comment: I actually end up doing that, they have whitelisted some domains for me.

Comment: @Robert can you repost your suggestion as answer, I'll accept it as answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the office network is very restricted when it comes to network access.

May be you should better talk to your IT department if you can't get a PC that is located in a different subnet that is less restrictive. Or if you are lucky the change the configuration for your PC so that you can access the required servers without proxy.